# What do it refer to in the long with structure?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

In the article "Exploring the sea-floor" from "science survey" written by T.F.Gaskell:

> Since the sea covers the greater part of the earth's surface,it is quite reasonable to regard the sea-floor as the basic form of the crust of the earth, with superimposed upon it the continents, together with the islands and other features of the oceans.

For the long with structure:

> with superimposed upon it the continents, together with the islands and other features of the oceans.

We can infer from "regard sea-floor as the basic form of the crust of the earth" that "sea-floor" = "basic form of the crust of the earth",they are same things in author's point of view,so i parse it into :

> with the continents superimposed upon sea-floor , together with the islands and other features of the oceans.

or

> with the continents superimposed upon the basic form of the crust of the earth , together with the islands and other features of the oceans.

It seems like that it in "upon it the continents" refer to "sea-floor" or "the basic form of the crust of the earth".

Comment: What **does** x refer to. **The long with structure** does not mean anything.

Comment: It could be written "with the continents, together with the islands and other features of the oceans, superimposed upon it." But "the sea-floor" and "the basic form of the crust of the earth" are the same thing so it's unimportant which "it" relates to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are parsing it wrong.  The continents are superimposed upon the ocean floor -- that is, they are additions to the basic form of the ocean floor.